# android project for sending string to microcontroller via bluetooth

Tags: android, microcontroller, android-bluetooth

I want to make an application which should send a string over Bluetooth to a micro-controller..I am kind of new to android and don't know where to start..
if anyone could help me with code or what topics i should study to complete this project, it would be great help..
thanx in advance

Comment: What kind of micro-controller?arduino, rasweberry-pi,..etc

Comment: Firstly, you need to find out the ATMEGA-8 has a Bluetooth hardware. Reading a doc here: http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega8.aspx, and I think it does't, so you will need a Bluetooth module that will attach to the micro-controller in order to receive data

Comment: thanx fr ur quick response...
i hav bluetooth module attached and its totally working when connected with device..i am just left with android to complete

Comment: thing is we are two people working on same project and he is done with micro-controller part nw m suppose to complete android portion..
thanx for ur link but that part is already completed....

Comment: I gotcha now. Look at the below answer. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You could visit the Bluetooth android documentation which shows you how to create a Bluetooth connection and retrieve data: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html
It is the same basic principle but just need to modify that your android device only connects to the specific address which is your micro-controller. Then, I guess you done. Make sure that your micro-controller understands and can handle your Bluetooth messages.

Comment: now my Bluetooth is getting enabled and searching for devices in range its also displaying the paired devices.....but thing is i dont want user to select device for connection...
As i know mac address of micro-controller's bluetooth module so if its in range it should automatically connect with the same...and pair with it..so that when next time i switch on my app it should search in list of paired device n get connected